# Simple Boost Python tutorial for visual studio C++

Tags: python, c++, boost

Hi I have installed boost https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.60.0/

I am trying to complete this tutorial http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/hello.html

I am stuck at running bjam. It says use cmd line and type bjam. I get the error below. someone please help !!!

```
PS C:\Program Files\boost_1_61_0\libs\python\example\tutorial> bjam

bjam : The term 'bjam' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ bjam
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (bjam:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PS C:\Program Files\boost_1_61_0\libs\python\example\tutorial>
```

i have bjam in my folder

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I have bjam in my folder"? Do you mean that in `C:\Program Files\boost_1_61_0\libs\python\example\tutorial` you have a file called `bjam.exe`?

Comment: I have bjam in C:\Program Files\boost_1_61_0 (i got it after running bootstrap.bat). I tried shifting bjam to the tutorial folder but it didnt do anything useful. I can double click on bjam and something happens. I cannot run bjam using cmd line even though C:\Program Files\boost_1_61_0 is in my environment PATH

Comment: I dont know how to start up bjam. i also dunno how to do ECHO %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%

Comment: I type that in cmd line but it give me nothing

Comment: ECHO %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% doesnt show anything

Comment: There's little reason to use bjam, it's a library like any other -- you just need to set the include paths (to boost and to appropriate Python headers) and link with the appropriate .lib

Comment: I am extremely unskilled in all these. I just know how to write code. I hope you can explain what you mean by that or maybe post a link to an extremely simple tutorial / video ? I just need a working example so I can continue on with my work.

Comment: I know how to set include paths, and write code. I have 0 idea how to call a c++ function from python. And i still am totally clueless what to do now that bjam isnt working for me

Comment: How do i link with the appropriate lib ? I have the following files similar to the tutorial.hello.cpp
hello.py
Jamroot

Comment: What specific compiler/IDE/build tools do you use? Do you know how to create a shared library (.dll) with it (I mean setting it up, not writing any of the code)?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your continued help! I am using visual studio 2013. I have followed and completed the tutorial at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ms235636.aspx (Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library (C++)) after reading your post. I do see a shared library after compiling the code provided by the tutorial. So I guess I know how to create a shared library (.dll) now